# Verify email in Laravel 9

Tags: laravel, email, laravel-9, verification

I want to do email verification. Actually, it succeeded, but only to the email in the .env file. Why didn't other users receive the email verification link?

**Model**

```
class User extends Authenticatable implements MustVerifyEmail
```

**web**

```
Auth::routes(['verify' => true]);
```

**controller**

```
$this-\>middleware(\['auth', 'verified'\]);
```

**.env**

```
MAIL_MAILER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp.gmail.com
MAIL_PORT=465
MAIL_USERNAME=mymail@gmail.com
MAIL_PASSWORD=zdmqlfstftkdvrsz
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=tls
MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS="hello@example.com"
MAIL_FROM_NAME="Travel"
```

Why was it only sent to mymail but not to other emails?

Comment: Did you receive an error? If not, this isn't a programming question, and impossible to solve without access to mail server logs.

Answer (score 0):

You could try to make MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS equal to MAIL_USERNAME. If that does not match it can be disallowed

Answer (score 0):

If you want to debug this further, you can temporarily modify the `sendEmailVerificationNotification()` method in your User model to log some info.

```
public function sendEmailVerificationNotification()
{
    $email = $this->getEmailForVerification();

    // Log the email address to which the verification link would be sent
    Log::info('Sending email verification link to: ' . $email);

    $this->notify(new Notifications\VerifyEmail);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS needs to be an actual email address that exists. I realized that made-up email addresses like "hello@example.com" don't work.